# RecyclerView never show

Tags: android, kotlin

I try get data from internet, after done i update my `Recyclerview`, but it never show. Method `onDone()` Toast size of `result`, it's not empty.

My code:

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var requestSearchPresenter: RequestSearchPresenter
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter
    private var searchResult = ArrayList<ItemNewFeedCollection?>()

    private val onRequestSearchResult = object : OnRequestSearchResult {
        override fun onEmpty(result: ListNewFeedCollection) {
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onDone(result: ListNewFeedCollection) {
            searchResult = result.post
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "${searchResult.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onFail(t: String) {
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private var recyclerViewItemClickListener = object : OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(view: View, postion: Int) {
            (requireActivity() as NewFeedActivity).apply {
                val post = searchResult
                if (post[postion]!!.date == "null" && post[postion]!!.date == post[postion]!!.description &&
                    post[postion]!!.date == post[postion]!!.full_post && post[postion]!!.date == post[postion]!!.image &&
                    post[postion]!!.date == post[postion]!!.full_post
                ) {
                } else {
                    val link = post[postion]!!.link
                    val source = post[postion]!!.source
                    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), PostActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("link", link)
                    intent.putExtra("source", source)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onLongItemClick(view: View, postion: Int) {
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    }

    private fun configRecyclerView() {
        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(requireContext(), searchResult, recyclerViewItemClickListener)

        recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recycler_view.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        configRecyclerView()

        val keyWord = arguments?.getString("key_word")

        keyWord?.let {
            requestSearchPresenter = RequestSearchPresenter(onRequestSearchResult)
            requestSearchPresenter.search(it)
        }
    }
}
```

But i move method `configRecyclerView()` to `onDone()`, it show on:

```
override fun onDone(result: NewFeedCollection) {
        searchResult = result.post
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "${searchResult.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        configRecyclerView()

        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `fun onDone` you are reassigning the result:  `searchResult = result.post`
Instead of that you **have to update the list's reference you've passed to the adapter initially**. That means you need to change the code:
from:

```
searchResult = result.post
```

to

```
searchResult.clear();
searchResult.addAll(result.post);
```